# How to make HTTP POST request with url encoded body in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make an post request in flutter with content type as url encoded. When I write `body : json.encode(data)`, it encodes to plain text.

If I write `body: data` I get the error `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

This is the data object

```
var match = {
  "homeTeam": {"team": "Team A"},
  "awayTeam": {"team": "Team B"}
};
```

And my request

```
var response = await post(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: match,
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add three additional steps:
First, you need to convert the JSON map to a String (using json.encode)
Then you need to Uri encode it if you want to send it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Lastly, you need to give the parameter that you are posting a name.

For example (note, this is using the dart:io HttpClient, but it's basically the same):

```
  Future<HttpClientResponse> foo() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      'homeTeam': {'team': 'Team A'},
      'awayTeam': {'team': 'Team B'},
    };
    String jsonString = json.encode(jsonMap); // encode map to json
    String paramName = 'param'; // give the post param a name
    String formBody = paramName + '=' + Uri.encodeQueryComponent(jsonString);
    List<int> bodyBytes = utf8.encode(formBody); // utf8 encode
    HttpClientRequest request =
        await _httpClient.post(_host, _port, '/a/b/c');
    // it's polite to send the body length to the server
    request.headers.set('Content-Length', bodyBytes.length.toString());
    // todo add other headers here
    request.add(bodyBytes);
    return await request.close();
  }
```

The above is for the `dart:io` version (which, of course, you can use in Flutter)
If you would like to stick with the `package:http` version, then you need to tweak your Map a bit. `body` must be a `Map<String, String>`. You need to decide what you want as your POST parameters. Do you want two: homeTeam and awayTeam? or one, say, teamJson?

This code

```
  Map<String, String> body = {
    'name': 'doodle',
    'color': 'blue',
    'homeTeam': json.encode(
      {'team': 'Team A'},
    ),
    'awayTeam': json.encode(
      {'team': 'Team B'},
    ),
  };

  Response r = await post(
    url,
    body: body,
  );
```

produces this on the wire

> name=doodle&color=blue&homeTeam=%7B%22team%22%3A%22Team+A%22%7D&awayTeam=%7B%22team%22%3A%22Team+B%22%7D

alternatively, this

```
  Map<String, String> body = {
    'name': 'doodle',
    'color': 'blue',
    'teamJson': json.encode({
      'homeTeam': {'team': 'Team A'},
      'awayTeam': {'team': 'Team B'},
    }),
  };

  Response r = await post(
    url,
    body: body,
  );
```

produces this on the wire

> name=doodle&color=blue&teamJson=%7B%22homeTeam%22%3A%7B%22team%22%3A%22Team+A%22%7D%2C%22awayTeam%22%3A%7B%22team%22%3A%22Team+B%22%7D%7D

the `package:http` client takes care of: encoding the Uri.encodeQueryComponent, utf8 encoding (note that that's the default, so no need to specify it) and sending the length in the Content-Length header. You must still do the json encoding.

Comment: If you don't care for a specific port, httpClient.postUrl also works!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it seems that this solution is only working for objects that are not embedded with other objects. Hence if I remove the homeTeam object and awayTeam object, it works fine.

Comment: according to documentation-  _[body] sets the body of the request. It can be a [String], a [List<int>] or a [Map<String, String>]. If it's a String, it's encoded using [encoding] and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will default to "text/plain"._

Comment: So I have to set the content type to `application/json` if I want to send complex structures. url-encoded will only work for single level objects.

Comment: How to pass several params using HttpClientRequest?

Comment: I have tried this but my app kept crashing.

Answer (score 31):

I'd like to recommend [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) package to you , [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) is a powerful Http client for Dart/Flutter, which supports Interceptors, FormData, Request Cancellation, File Downloading, Timeout etc.

[dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) is very easy to use, in your case you can:

```
Map<String, String> body = {
'name': 'doodle',
'color': 'blue',
'teamJson': {
  'homeTeam': {'team': 'Team A'},
  'awayTeam': {'team': 'Team B'},
  },
};

dio.post("/info",data:body, options: 
  new Options(contentType:ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
```

[dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) can encode the data automatically.

More details please refer to [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio).

Comment: Looks promising. @wendu what are the benefits using this module?

Comment: If you are affiliated with the package, please disclose your affiliation in the post.

Comment: This won't even compile, it should be an Map of `<String, dynamic>` and not `<String, String>`

Comment: check [Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

Answer (score 27):

I came here just trying to make an HTTP POST request. Here is an example of how to do that:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';


makePostRequest() async {

  final uri = Uri.parse('http://httpbin.org/post');
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {'id': 21, 'name': 'bob'};
  String jsonBody = json.encode(body);
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

  Response response = await post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonBody,
    encoding: encoding,
  );

  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  String responseBody = response.body;
}
```

See also

- [How to make HTTP requests in Flutter](https://suragch.medium.com/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef)

Comment: If I add a Bearer token in the header, its now working

Comment: @Vipin, good point. Some APIs require adding credentials in the header.

Comment: I meant, In that case the API is not sending the headers. Did you ever try that?

Comment: @Vipin, I talk about authentication at the end of [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef).

Comment: this was helpful, especially cause it hinted me to use https://httpbin.org/ lovely service for api debugging

Comment: I used this but my app crashed on the execution of this piece of code.

Comment: @Ayesha Iftikhar, you need to use `Uri.parse` now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have used that but in my case my pub.lock file was generating that error and causing crash so I just delete that file and get the dependencies again and run the app and its working fine now.

Answer (score 14):

you need to use json.encode

example;

```
var match = {
  "homeTeam": {"team": "Team A"},
  "awayTeam": {"team": "Team B"}
};
var response = await post(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: json.encode(match),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
```

Comment: That encoding part really helped me.

Comment: In http/http.dart, it will not work if we encode the body using json.encode. Just pass the body as a map and it will be encoded as form fields using encoding.

Comment: This is what completed the example for me. I made a map but passing it as a parameter to http.post (in body) didn't make it. Encoding it, my PHP rest api could read it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library. It supports a lot with working with APIs.

With newest Dio version. Simply do the following:

```
BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
baseUrl: "https://www.xx.com/api",
connectTimeout: 5000,
receiveTimeout: 3000,);
Dio dio = new Dio(options);
//
Map<String, String> params = Map();
params['username'] = '6388';
params['password'] = '123456';
//
response = await dio.post("/login", data: FormData.fromMap(params));
```

Answer (score 1):

On the place of "UserModel" write the name of your model and do not pass String in the body it will create a problem using "Map" as given below.

```
static Future<UserModel> performUserLogin(String username, String password) async{
    
        try{
    
          Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
          
    
          Map<String, String> JsonBody = {
            'username':  username,
            'password': password
          };
    
          print("The JSON Object is here $body");
          // make POST request
          final response = await http.post(loginAPIURL,body: JsonBody);
          // check the status code for the result
          int statusCode = response.statusCode;
          print("Login calling $response");
    
    
          if (statusCode == 200){
    
          
    
          }else{
            return null;
            //return UserModel();
            throw Exception("Error in login");
          }
    
        } catch (e) {
          throw Exception(e);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Post encoded URL request

```
 static Future<http.Response> genearalRequest() async {
  Map<String,String> headers = new Map();
  headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
 var data = {
    "data1": "datat1 value",
    "data2": "value2"
   };
var parts = [];
data.forEach((key, value) {
  parts.add('${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key)}='
      '${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value)}');
});
var formData = parts.join('&');

print(formData);
return await http.post('$baseUrl/oauth/token', headers: headers, body: formData);
```

}

[Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/HttpRequest/postFormData.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dio you can do it using :

```
dio.post(
      '/info',
      data: {'id': 5},
      options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType),
    );
```

check https://github.com/flutterchina/dio for more details

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this with dart's http package. It's not too fancy. My endpoint wasn't accepting the parameters with other methods, but it accepted them like this, with the brackets included in the parameter.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = "<URL>";

Map<String, String> match = {
  "homeTeam[team]": "Team A",
  "awayTeam[team]": "Team B",
};

Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers).then((response){
    print(response.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> body = {
  'getDetails': 'true'
};

final response = await 
http.post("https://example.com/", body: body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addAll()...

```
var multipart = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("userfile", file.path);//userFile must match server

var requestMultipart = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("uri"));

requestMultipart.files.add(multipart);

Map<String, String> data = {
  "name_of_image": "testName",
  "id_image": "2",//if the
  "upload_type": "Insert",
  "id_location": "2"
};

requestMultipart.fields.addAll(data);
```