# Flutter WCF Service Calling

Tags: wcf, soap, dart, flutter

i want to call our wcf services from flutter with dart without configuration of any addition settings. It is possible to access directly to wcf service method? I didn't find any approach to this.There is no package to implement soap services or wcf services in flutter pub web page. I am waiting suggestions or approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Flutter personaly, but I am going to borrow a few answers from SO to answer your question,

According to [How to make HTTP POST request with url encoded body in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797558/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-url-encoded-body-in-flutter) , flutter should have the ability to create HttpPosts/gets

```
Future<HttpClientResponse> foo() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      'homeTeam': {'team': 'Team A'},
      'awayTeam': {'team': 'Team B'},
    };
    String jsonString = json.encode(jsonMap); // encode map to json
    String paramName = 'param'; // give the post param a name
    String formBody = paramName + '=' + Uri.encodeQueryComponent(jsonString);
    List<int> bodyBytes = utf8.encode(formBody); // utf8 encode
    HttpClientRequest request =
        await _httpClient.post(_host, _port, '/a/b/c');
    // it's polite to send the body length to the server
    request.headers.set('Content-Length', bodyBytes.length.toString());
    // todo add other headers here
    request.add(bodyBytes);
    return await request.close();
  }
```

With the above Code taken from the linked post, now you can modify your WCF service a bit to now use REST instead of only SOAP, 
then just send a simple HTTP Request to the service and you will get your intended response

You can check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services on how to get started with WCF Rest

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i want to access wcf service directly, no making any configuraiton for service. Because I have many wcf service from multiple project. I can use all of them so it is extra workload. If i read directly, it is perfect for me.Native Android platfrom includes ksoap libraary, also does it have in flutter?