# Flutter Post Login with email and password with Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to implement in Flutter using a Post request login procedure using the email & password using the `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

with no success and always returns a 404 status code.

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    var bodyEncoded = json.encode(body);
    print(bodyEncoded);
    var response = await http.post(url, body: bodyEncoded , headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },);

print(response.status);
```

Comment: 404 indicates that the server wasn't able to match the URL path with anything it serves. Sounds like your URL is incorrect. Try using a tester like Postman first, so practice using the API. Also @Nuts is correct - you are converting the body to json, rather than letting the client encode it as form data.

Comment: @RichardHeap thank you very much, its indeed a wrong path, i just checked and made it from localhost into 10.0.2.2 in my path. Thank you!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67559979/6314955

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `body` must be an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Convert your `body` map to an `urlencoded` string this way:

```
String encodedBody = body.keys.map((key) => "$key=${body[key]}").join("&");
```

Then pass it to `http.post`'s body, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! greatly appreaciated, when I am looking to the Code Generation Snippet of Insomia Rest App, its indeed like this in this format about the email and password. This is it. Godbless! oh! I owe you much!

Comment: Your solution doesn't correctly URL encode all strings. This should be left to the HTTP client, by simply changing the request to `http.post(url, body: body, `

Comment: its all working now! SUCCESS! thank you guys for your inputs! @magicleon94 grazie! the additional solution I did after encoding the body as suggested by magicleaon94, and then I changed the proxy of my Android Emulator from localhost to 10.0.2.2 and I added into the AndroidManifest.xml file this "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>"

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. 
It's `application/json`.

Check if your URL is correct and if you really need to make request with encoded body:
[How to make HTTP POST request with url encoded body in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797558/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-url-encoded-body-in-flutter)

Comment: this content type in header is required during login with passport using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded on my Laravel API. My API functions well with Insomia but I cant replicate it on my Flutter App. Anyway thanks for the input.