# fetch data from an API with the use of ID in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I work on a delivery man application  and I need to have from an API the details of an order received on the account of a delivery man.

here is an example:

```json
{
    "Status": "1",
    "Order": {
        "deliveryCost": "5.000",
        "amount": "38.400",
        "total": "43,400",
        "hors_remise": "34.560",
        "Dishes": [
            {
                "cartID": "00000",
                "dishID": "13548",
                "dimensionID": 0,
                "title": "Classic 16 pieces trays:",
                "ingredient": "10 piece trays + 2 gunkan + 4 shrimp crunchy",
                "price": "38.400",
                "quantity": "1",
                "imagePath": "https://www.monresto.net/test/plats/P_170121112803.jpg",
                "Options": []
            }
        ],
```

and to access of all this information I must specify the "KEY" I had on the postan

my question is how can i add  (orderID)?

there is my code :

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class datePageClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _datePageClassState createState() => _datePageClassState();
}

class _datePageClassState extends State<datePageClass> {

  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
        'https://api/ws/v3/Delivery/orderDetails.php');

    if (respo
nse.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      var cmddetails = jsonDecode(data);
      print(cmddetails);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    print('');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Dart but I'd guess you want one of these answers: [How to make HTTP POST request with url encoded body in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49797558).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-check: Are your sure that this URL expects http-POST not http-GET?

You want to add `orderID` to the request, right?
If that's the case, first you need to find if API expects this parameter as query parameter or part of the body.

Nevertheless, here are examples for both cases.

`String orderDetailsUrl = 'https://www.monresto.net/ws/v3/Delivery/orderDetails.php';`

1. orderID as query parameter:

```
orderDetailsUrl += "?orderID=FIXME_ORDER_ID";  
http.Response response = await http.post(orderDetailsUrl);
```

2. `orderID` as part of request body:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = Map()
      ..putIfAbsent("orderID", () => "FIXME_ORDER_ID")
var body = jsonEncode(data);
http.Response response = await http.post(orderDetailsUrl, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
```

Comment: @orage thx for the solution and can u know just change the url because i can't delete this ask –

Comment: @beerstorm can use this for query params -   var _response = await _employeeModel.getEmployeeIfscDetail(jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{APIKey.IFSC: ifsc}),token);

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
var response = await http.post('https://www.apiurl.com/ws/v2/details.php',  body: {'OrderID': 1209, 'OtherParam': 'value'});
```

Then in PHP

```
$OrderID = $_POST["OrderID"];
$OtherParam = $_POST["OtherParam"];
```

Make sure to sanitize the variables to avoid `SQL Injections`

And then you can send JSON back to dart/flutter.

Comment: @oussamaayadi yes did it. If my solution helped you, please accept it as right answer, so that my solution will help others.

Comment: how to do this with get request api with one required parameter?