# Receiving Invalid request error from stripe while creating payment intent using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, payment

I am integrating Stripe in my flutter app, want to create payment intent using http POST request having mention [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#creating-a-paymentintent). But I am constantly receiving this error. Tried many thing!

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: {\"amount\":2,\"currency\":\"usd\"}",
    "param": "{\"amount\":2,\"currency\":\"usd\"}",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

My api function is this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createPaymentIntent(int amount) async {
    try {
      var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents";

      var body = json.encode({
        "amount": amount,
        "currency": 'usd'
      });

      var headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer '+stripeSecret
      };

      await http.post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: headers, encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")).then((response) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          print(response.body);
          return json.decode(response.body);
        }
        else{
          return response.reasonPhrase;
        }
      });

    } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

**Note**: `'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` is necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a JSON encoded body to the Stripe API, but the Stripe API expects a [form-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) [request body](https://stripe.com/docs/api):

> Our API has predictable resource-oriented URLs, accepts **form-encoded** request bodies, returns JSON-encoded responses, and uses standard HTTP response codes, authentication, and verbs.

Comment: So how can I do that in Flutter?

Comment: I have already mentioned that `'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` is necessay

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797558/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-url-encoded-body-in-flutter